# Rearranging data rows

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have a data frame with 2 variables (columns) and 108 rows and I need to rearrange the order of the rows for both columns as following: 1, 2, 3, 55, 56, 57, 4, 5, 6, 58, 59, 60, 7, 8, 9, 61, 62, 63, 10, 11, 12, 64, 65, 66, 13, 14, 15, 67, 68, 69, 16, 17, 18, 70, 71, 72, 19, 20, 21, 73, 74, 75, 22, 23, 24, 76, 77, 78, 25, 26, 27, 79, 80, 81, 28, 29, 30, 82, 83, 84, 31, 32, 33, 85, 86, 87, 34, 35, 36, 88, 89, 90, 37, 38, 39, 91, 92, 93, 40, 41, 42, 94, 95, 96, 43, 44, 45, 97, 98, 99, 46, 47, 48, 100, 101, 102, 49, 50, 51, 103, 104, 105, 52, 53, 54, 106, 107, 108...for this I am trying to use the dplyr arrange function with no success though. Could anyone help to troubleshoot this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this programmatically.  Create the sequence of rows vector ('v1'), then convert it to a `matrix` with 2 columns ('m1'), `split` the data.frame converted `matrix` with a grouping variable created with `gl` so that we split at every 3 columns to create a `list` of `data.frame`s, loop over the `list` with `lapply`, transpose (`t`), and convert the `matrix` to `vector` (`c`), `unlist` the `list` elements and use that as index for subsetting.  The transpose is done so that when we do the concatenate (`c`), it can make use of the default behavior i.e. columnwise order in getting the values as a vector.

```
v1 <- seq_len(nrow(df1))
m1 <- matrix(v1, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
ind <- unlist(lapply(split.default(as.data.frame(m1), 
         as.integer(gl(ncol(m1), 3, ncol(m1)))), function(x) c(t(x)))) 
df1[ind,]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, we do the same approach, by creating row_number column, then grouped by a column created with `gl`, we `arrange` the rows

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   transmute(v1 = row_number())  %>%
   group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), n()/2, n()))) %>%
   group_by(grp1 = gl(n(), 3, n())) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   arrange(grp1) %>% 
   pull(v1) %>% 
   arrange(df1, .)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Since I am new to R, the easiest way for me was to create a new variable and sort the data according to that column. I will try your codes too. Could you please add short comments to them and briefly explain the commands and functions used? Many thanks again. E.

Comment: @EvaBalgova Thank you.  I added some explanation.  Hope it helps.